# Is there any way to read from a .csv file without the use of getline()?

Tags: c++, string, csv

In a project that was assigned to me, that has to do with reading .csv files, my teacher made it clear that I cannot use strings. Wherever I have looked for help, the only solution I have found is the use of the function getline(), which only takes strings. Is there any other possible way to do it?

Comment: Has your teacher given any indication of what you should use instead of strings?

Comment: For reading files, try to use standard c function [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/). It's also one of the fastest ways of reading a file. Then you can iterate over a buffer of data and find newline characters yourself.

Comment: Is `std::string` the only thing from the standard library that you are not allowed to use?

Comment: No, he has not given any indication as to what I could use and yes, std::string is the only library I cannot use.

Comment: What CSV have you got to read? What is the content?

Comment: Every cell has both characters and numbers,as it contains registration numbers of students.

Comment: "_`std::string` is the only library I cannot use_" - Nice. Take a look at `std::vector`. With a `std::vector<char>` you could build something acting similar to a `std::string` and add your homemade `getline` to fill it. `istream` has `get()` and `peek()` to extract/look ahead, but it's a little tricky to get right.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your teacher is expecting you to test the input one character at a time (until end of line), and so is looking to see you do things such as

- test for end of file
- read characters and save progressively into variables
- test for the comma character and write out the current variable
- ignore characters that aren't part of your required input. (You didn't mention whether the CSV is of strings or of numeric values, but if the exercise was to identify integer values then you'd be rejecting all non-numeric characters.

Avoiding strings is technically not possible (since that is what a CSV is!) but I would guess the intention is to get you understanding streams as characters and writing logic to do with each character at a time.

Comment: Avoiding strings is always possible. Just use char arrays.

Comment: @sanitizedUser A string in computer science is a sequence of characters, which is what Howard is referring to.